# Equipment rental in Southwark, London, UK

Tags: renting

What reputable stores around the area could rent me a high-end DSLR such as the Nikon D800 and a high quality telephoto lens such as the Nikkor 135/2.0. I will be heading there in a few weeks and do not know the area at all.

Comment: If you're asking for equipment rentals in London, you're probably fine.  If "Southwark, Londion" is someplace I'm unfamiliar with and smaller - this should be closed as too localized.  Do you mean just London?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fixation](http://www.fixationuk.com/Fixation/Rental.html) are two stops on the tube from Southwark, I've used them before and they are very highly regarded.....but they don't have the D800 or 135 f/2.0. They have the 200 f/2.0, which is a significantly better lens.

It seems none of the rental shops have the D800 yet, it's too new. Are you coming to the Olympics? If so the D3s would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I would like to rent the D800 for the additional resolution. My second best option is the 5DMKIII with the Canon 135 f/2.

Comment: I rented the D800 at Fixation finally. Their service was top notch and the equipment was in great shape.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing more than Gargoyle tells me about the subject, BUT 'Fixation'  [= these people sound excellent](http://www.fixationuk.com/Fixation/Fixation%20-%20Home/Fixation%20-%20Home.html). They do not list D800 yet but will obviously have them when they can and do have eg 5D MkIII. (THey do have D3, D3s, D3x, D700)

[Their rental page here](http://www.fixationuk.com/Fixation/Rental.html)
 5DMkIII is GBP110/day and GBP440/week as a guide.
 The Canon EF 135mm f/2 is GBP 33/132 per day/week.

---

They "feel"  better than eg [these people](http://www.directphotographic.co.uk/camerarental/dslr.asp#nikon) (also no D800) who have 5DMKIII for just less.

They offer this nice [downloadable PDF pricelist](http://www.directphotographic.co.uk/downloads/pricelist/directpricelist.pdf)  which may be worth looking at as an overall market guide.

Phase One IQ 180 digital back GBP395/day ! :-(

---

'Fixation have a similar price but somehow better "feel" [than these people](http://www.centralrental.co.uk/dslr.html)
 Catchy name - "Central Rental" :-)